# SQL INNER JOIN duplicating data on output?

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I am using SQL Server 2008 and trying to join data from 4 different tables where the tables are related such that the 2nd table is a child of the 1st and the 3rd & 4th tables are BOTH children of the 2nd, I am using the following statement to output the results but rather than getting 9 distinct records (5 from the CR table and 4 from the CX table) I am getting 20 records where data from the 3rd & 4th tables is duplicated.

If I omit references to table CX I get the desired 5 results and omitting references to CR gives the desired 4 results, however I require the 9 results from both tables combined returned instead of the 20 records I do get. I would post screenshots but am unable due to reputation sorry.

```
SELECT
        LS.SITECODE,
        ep.EP_KEY,
        C0.LEASEID,
        C0.SDATE AS LeaseStart,
        C0.EDATE AS LeaseExpiry, 
        CR.EFFDATE AS RenewalDate,
        CX.SDATE AS ReviewDate     
    FROM LS
    INNER JOIN FMEP AS ep ON LS.SITECODE = ep.SITECODE
    INNER JOIN C0 ON ep.EP_KEY = C0.EP_KEY
    INNER JOIN CR ON C0.LEASEID = CR.LEASEID
    INNER JOIN CX ON C0.LEASEID = CX.LEASEID                                           
    WHERE ls.SITECODE = 2121
```

I have searched around for the last couple of hours for a solution however I'm obviously not using the correct search terms due to my lack of familiarity with SQL. I am new to SQL so please be patient if I struggle to understand your responses and thank you in advance for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: example data, expected output....

Comment: You can use [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) to add some data sample and table schemas.

Comment: Given CR has 5 values for leaseid and CX has 4 values for leaseid, based on your descriptions on omitting joins; and they are inner joined, I don't understand why you're expecting 9 rows in the result?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you right, you want C0  joined with CR
and then c0 joined with CX ( so you get 5 and 4 rows)

yet you get 5 rows from one join and 4 rows from the other join. the DBMS doesn't know how to connect these two joins and make a little cross join ( every 4 rows with the 5 other rows) resulting in 20 rows ( if i understand your description in the right way)

here is a soution you get the 9 rows you want.

```
SELECT
        LS.SITECODE,
        ep.EP_KEY,
        C0.LEASEID,
        C0.SDATE AS LeaseStart,
        C0.EDATE AS LeaseExpiry, 
        CR.EFFDATE AS RenewalDate,
        'CR'
    FROM LS
    INNER JOIN FMEP AS ep ON LS.SITECODE = ep.SITECODE
    INNER JOIN C0 ON ep.EP_KEY = C0.EP_KEY
    INNER JOIN CR ON C0.LEASEID = CR.LEASEID
    WHERE ls.SITECODE = 2121
UNION
SELECT
        LS.SITECODE,
        ep.EP_KEY,
        C0.LEASEID,
        C0.SDATE,
        C0.EDATE, 
        CX.SDATE   
        'CX'  
    FROM LS
    INNER JOIN FMEP AS ep ON LS.SITECODE = ep.SITECODE
    INNER JOIN C0 ON ep.EP_KEY = C0.EP_KEY
    INNER JOIN CX ON C0.LEASEID = CX.LEASEID     
    WHERE ls.SITECODE = 2121
```

but if you just want the C0 row once, ( with eather an CX or a CR you have to do a better join )